# Titanium create table view replacing existing view

Tags: titanium, tableview

I have a dream... No that's not it.
I have a view, and all works fine until i add createTableView. 
When i do it replaces everything that came out on the screen prior to it.
How do i have the mapview and the tableview at the same time?

```
var self = Ti.UI.createView();

var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    top:1,
    height:200,
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region:{latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993, latitudeDelta:0.5, longitudeDelta:0.5},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true
});

self.add(mapview);

var lbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Please select an item',
    height:'auto',
    width:'auto',
    color:'#000'
});
self.add(lbl);

self.addEventListener('itemSelected', function(e) {
    lbl.text = e.name+': $'+e.price;
});

detailData = [{title:"Foo",leftImage:"bar.png",hasChild:true}];


var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data:detailData
});
// if i dont rem the below line all i get on screen is the table view
self.add(table);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TableView control usually takes over the whole screen, I would try adding the MapView to one of the rows of the TableView, [however, this may not work on Android](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-10317):

```
// Create the table
var self = Ti.UI.createView();
var detailData = [{title:"Foo",leftImage:"bar.png",hasChild:true}];
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data : detailData
});
self.add(table);

// Create the mapview
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    top:1,
    height:200,
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region:{latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993, latitudeDelta:0.5, longitudeDelta:0.5},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true
});

// Insert a row in first index of the table that has the mapview in it
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
row.add(mapview);
table.insertRowBefore(1, row);
```

**EDIT:**

Oops, well the easier way is to just to set the height of the table, and make your container view have a vertical layout:

```
// Create the container view
var self = Ti.UI.createView({
    layout : 'vertical'
});
// Add the mapview
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    height:200,
});
self.add(mapview);
// Add the table
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    top : 0,
    data : detailData
});
self.add(table);
```

Comment: Curses... Is there something similar one can use?

Comment: Can i add html of some sort?

Comment: Try the edits, although the table view row method works great IMO